# How to run function in remote server using ssh and expect?

Tags: bash, expect

I need to run a function on a remote server over SSH. I'm using expect to automate login to remote server. On remote machine, I can run command, local scripts, but function is not working. I get "bash: foo: command not found". Maybe function definition is not sent to remore server the same way a command is sent. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo(){ ls -la; }    # to run in remote machine

cmd="ls -la"
func="foo"

ip='1.2.3.4'
pass='abcd'

export ip pass cmd func

    /usr/bin/expect <(cat <<-'EOF'
    set timeout 60

    # spawn ssh -t $::env(ip) "ls -la"          # Working
    # spawn ssh -t $::env(ip) $::env(cmd)       # Working
    # spawn ssh -t $::env(ip) $::env(func)      # Not working; bash: foo: command not found
    # spawn ssh -t $::env(ip) "$(typeset -f $::env(func)); $::env(func)"    # Not working
        expect {
            "yes/no" {
                send "yes\r"
                exp_continue
            }
            "*assword*" { send "$::env(pass)\r" }
        }
        interact
    EOF
    )

echo -e "\nDone."
```

Is it possible to run function on remote machine using ssh/expect?

Comment: `export` does not work across ssh.

Comment: @pynexj I used export to make bash variables available in heredoc `expect`. Both `ip` and `pass` interpreted well in `ssh` but problem was with the function `foo`.

Comment: you are not exporting the *definition* of the func. use `export -f` for that though it won't work across ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Worked after storing the entire function in a variable(as string) and then exporting it.

```
func='foo(){
    hostname;
    ls -la;
    date; }'
```

Using `typeset` I can execute this function on a remote host via `ssh`. Since function definition was not available inside `expect`, it did not work.

Here's my full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

func='foo(){
    hostname;
    ls -la;
    date; }'

ip='1.2.3.4'
pass='abcd'

export func ip pass

    /usr/bin/expect <(cat <<-'EOF'
    set timeout 60

    spawn ssh $::env(ip) "$::env(func); foo"

        expect {
            "yes/no" {
                send "yes\r"
                exp_continue
            }
            "*assword*" { send "$::env(pass)\r" }
        }

        interact

    EOF
    )

echo -e "\nDone."
```

The solution works fine but it seems stupid to myself. Hoping someone could give a better alternative.